# How to reload image on page, with same URL?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to reload image on page. I trying this:

```
 $("#ill2d").attr("src", decision.Illustration + "#" + new Date().getTime());
```

But, image toggle on alt text. If I press F5, it work, and image is reloaded.

**UPDATE**
I tried to do as advised:

```
$("#ill2d").attr("src", decision.Illustration + "?time=" + new Date().getTime());
```

But it still does not work, image toggle on alt text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#ill2d").attr("src", $("#ill2d").attr("src") + "?" + (+new Date()));
```

Assuming the src is not changing, since you only want to refresh the current one set. This also asumes no timestamp currently are in the URI (no and-sign set).

Answer (score 0):

A way to tell the browser you want to reload "another" image is to change the img src attribute. I suppose your img name is simple, like `image.jpg`, `/path/to/img.png` etc. (you do not have things like `?get=48`).

You can make the browser "think" you want another image is displayed, you need to change the image url every time.

```
var img_src = 'path/to/image.png';

$('#ill2d').attr('src', img_src + '?rand=' + Math.random());
```

We store the original image src in a variable in order not to get url like this - `path/to/img.png?123?456?789`. (*It is not wrong* but seems weird)

Answer (score 0):

In your code example:

```
 $("#ill2d").attr("src", decision.Illustration + "#" + new Date().getTime());
```

The # is purely a client-side thing, it is not involved in url-based caching and is not sent to the server. Use a question mark instead and pass a query parameter.